# Multiple interval ratio of E[X / (X + Y)]

Tags: expected-value, stochastic-processes

I have a sequence of interchanging on- and off-intervals, each pair identified by index $i$. The duration of the on-interval $i$ is represented by random variable $X_i$, and the duration of the off-interval $i$ is represented by random variable $Y_i$. All $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are independent from each other. Every $X_i$ is independently drawn from the same distribution as $X$, as well every $Y_i$ is independently drawn from the same distribution as $Y$. With $n$ intervals there are $n$ draws $X_1, \dotsc, X_n$ and $Y_1, \dotsc, Y_n$.

I want to know the ratio:

$$E[lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}{Y_i}}]$$

Intuitively, and affirmed by some simulation I ran, I'm convinced this converges to:
$$\frac{E[X]}{E[X]+E[Y]}
$$
But I struggle with the mathematical proof of it due to the dependence between $X$ in the denominator and numerator.

Comment: Start by rewriting the denominator at $\sum_{i=1}^n{(X_i+Y_i)}$ and consider using a Taylor Series expansion of the ratio.

Comment: This is actually a special case of an *alternating renewal process*, and your hypothesis, which is true, is a consequence of the Blackwell Renewal Theorem:  http://www.ece.iisc.ernet.in/~parimal/spqt/lecture-08.pdf.

Comment: @jbowman Thank you, interesting observation. I understand how it follows from Corollary 2.2.